# Do Lord Vishnu,Ganesha and Saraswati have multiple consorts? If so who are they?

Tags: vishnu, ganesha, saraswati

When I was browsing through some questions here,I came across this:

> Now in contrast to Sita, who was an incarnation of Vishnu's wife Lakshmi, Vedavati was an incarnation of **Vishnu's other wife Bhumidevi**. And after Rama was reunited with Sita, he was asked to marry Vedavati, but he refused, saying that he can only marry one woman in this birth

I did some further research and found out that Lord Vishnu had many consorts such as Vaishno Devi and Padmavati. I also found out about the many wives of Ganesha, like Siddhi and Buddhi. I also found out that some people believe that Saraswati had married another person after escaping Brahma:

> Lakshmi and **Saraswati are wives of Vishnu**.

Some people would say "Vishnu is only married to Lakshmi" or "Ganesha is a bachelor", but others believe in multiple consorts. Can someone tell me about all of these deities'consorts and give a list?

Lastly,please visit and answer this question which is similar to this one :[Why did Shiva marry Ganga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10696/why-did-shiva-marry-ganga])

Comment: Thank God that there is no Lord Shiva this time ;) Lord Vishnu--Lakshmi,Bhumi,Nila.Lord Ganapaty-Siddhi,Budhhi,Kshemadayini.

Comment: @Rickross Who are Nila and Kshemadayini???Also can you post your answers **as** answers please?

Comment: Someone **please** give me a list!

Comment: In Vaikuntha LOrd Vishnu's Shakti are three in number and they are called Sri(lakshmi),Bhumi and Nila.From the mantra used for tarpanam "Kshemadayini sahitam Vighna rajam Tarpayami" Kshemadayini is Vighnaraj's shakti or consort whatever you may like to say.

Comment: See my question here for information on Vishnu's wife Niladevi: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7800/36

Comment: Vishnu's consort is Mother Laxmi, Ganesha's consorts are Ridhdhi Sidhdhi and Saraswati's consort is Lord Brahma.

Comment: Saraswati did not marry Lord Vishnu after escaping from Brahma or any such thing. According to the Devi Bhagavat Puran she, Lakshmi and Ganga were originally married to Lord Vishnu.